# How to select records from a table which do not have foreign key in another table

Tags: sql, database, h2

I've got 5 tables in my database
[image]

I want to select the `V_CODE` in `V` which records do not share **any** `S` foreign key with `F` when F_CODE = 'A'.

I tried something like

```
select distinct V_CODE
from V
         inner join V_S VS on V.V_ID = VS.V_FK
         inner join S on VS.S_FK = S.S_ID
where S._ID not in (
    select FS.S_FK
    from F
             inner join F_S on F.F_ID = F_S.F_FK
    where F.F_CODE = 'A'
    );
```

but this does not return exactly what I want.
Can someone give a help? Thanks in advance.

Table F

```
| F_ID |  F_CODE |
| 1    |    A    |
| 2    |    B    |
| 3    |    C    |
```

Table F_S

```
| F_FK |  S_FK  |
| 1    |    1   |
| 2    |    2   |
| 3    |    3   |
```

Table S

```
| S_ID |  S_CODE  |
| 1    |    S1    |
| 2    |    S2    |
| 3    |    S3    |
```

Table V_S

```
| V_FK |  S_FK  |
| 1    |    1   |
| 1    |    2   |
| 2    |    3   |
| 3    |    1   |
| 3    |    3   |
```

Table V

```
| V_ID |  V_CODE  |
| 1    |    V1    |
| 2    |    V2    |
| 3    |    V3    |
```

In this case I'd want to return only `V2` because it's the only record in table `V` not sharing a record in Table `S` when F_CODE = 'A'

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want `v_code`s that have no `f_code = 'A'` when you follow the relationships among the tables.

To me, this suggests `not exists`:

```
select v.*
from v
where not exists (select 1
                  from v_s join
                       f_s
                       on v_s.s_fk = f_s.s_fk join
                       f
                       on f_s.f_fk = f.f_id
                  where f.f_code = 'A' and vs.v_fk = v.v_id
                 );
```

Comment: this doesn't work to me. it returns empty. i'm using h2 in mem, i don't know if thats relevant

Comment: @znaya . . . Is there an error?  This is standard SQL so it should work.

Comment: no, just an empty result...anyway,  inspired by your suggestion i adapted to select the V_ID NOT IN V_S join F_S join F where F_CODE = 'A'. i'm still running some tests to make sure it really does what its meant

Comment: @znaya . . . I fixed the answer.  I left out the correlation clause to the outer query.  This should be faster than `not in`.

Comment: just remembered i didn't give you feedback, i'm sorry. it worked fine. thank you so much for the help